# How can I solve attribute error for Pandas : "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'StringDtype'"?

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, jupyter, attributeerror

pd.Series(["a","b","c"], dtype=pd.StringDtype())

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'StringDtype'

Answer (score 1):

You need upgrade pandas, because [`pandas.StringDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html) is implemented in pandas 1.0.0+:

> class pandas.StringDtype
> Extension dtype for string data.

> New in version 1.0.0.

Comment: ah I thought OP was using Pyspark dtypes instead of Pandas (with a slight typo) didn't know of this new dtype nice one.